# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value profile_view.dart:938:61)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Unhandled Exception:

> Null check operator used on a null value
> E/flutter (31702): #0      _ProfileViewState.login
> (package:.../profile/profile_view.dart:938:61)

profile_view.dart:938:61

```dart
 login(PhoneAuthCredential credential, RunMutation mutationCall) async {
    final UserCredential cr =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final String firebaseToken = await cr.user!.getIdToken();
    final args = LoginArguments(firebaseToken: firebaseToken).toJson();
    final netResult = await mutationCall(args).networkResult;
    ***final loginRes = Login$Mutation.fromJson(netResult!.data!);***
    final jwt = loginRes.login.jwtToken;
    Hive.box('user').put('jwt', jwt);
    setState(() {
      verifyState = StepState.complete;
      _currentStep = 2;
    });
  }
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: Can you try with `if(netResult!=null) {final loginRes = Login$Mutation.fromJson(netResult!.data!) ....}else{print("got null")}`

Comment: could you write full code please

Comment: Iam not sure if it will work because I am not aware of previous methods like `LoginArguments`... try null check after getting `netResult` like 
`final netResult = await mutationCall(args).networkResult;
    if (netResult != null && netResult!.data!=null) {
      final loginRes = Login$Mutation.fromJson(netResult!.data!);
      final jwt = loginRes.login.jwtToken;
      Hive.box('user').put('jwt', jwt);
      setState(() {
        verifyState = StepState.complete;
        _currentStep = 2;
      });
    }`

Comment: it gives same error

Comment: I will  encourage you to check null value from beginning like it is possible you are getting null user, don't use bang `!` without check null, do `if(value!=null) then use value!`.

Answer (score 0):

I will encourage not to use `!` directly without checking null. In this snippet there are few cases we can get null.

Before using `!` do a null check on the variable. like

```dart
final randomValue = .....;
if (randomValue != null) { 
   usingAfterCheckingNull  = randomValue!.variable
}
```

In your case, snippet  can be like

```dart
login(PhoneAuthCredential credential, RunMutation mutationCall) async {
    final UserCredential cr =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    if (cr.user == null) {
      debugPrint("go null user");
      return;
    }
    final String firebaseToken = await cr.user!.getIdToken();
    final args = LoginArguments(firebaseToken: firebaseToken).toJson();
    final netResult = await mutationCall(args).networkResult;

    if (netResult != null && netResult!.data != null) {
      final loginRes = Login$Mutation.fromJson(netResult!.data!);
      final jwt = loginRes.login.jwtToken;
      Hive.box('user').put('jwt', jwt);
      setState(() {
        verifyState = StepState.complete;
        _currentStep = 2;
      });
    } else {
      debugPrint("others error");
    }
  }
```

Comment: problem not solved.

Comment: What do you get now?cant tell for sure, because there are methods are unknown here